# Error invalid time series parameters specified - in backtesting R script

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have created this backtesting script and its executing but has a minor problem.

```
library(quantmod) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
tickers = 'AMZN'
symbol = getSymbols(tickers,from="2014-01-01",auto.assign=F)
head(symbol)
prices=Cl(symbol)
sma.fast=SMA(prices, 10)
sma.slow=SMA(prices, 20)
buy.signal = ifelse((sma.fast> sma.slow), 1, NA)
sell.signal=ifelse((sma.fast< sma.slow), -1, NA)
position=rowSums(cbind(buy.signal,sell.signal),na.rm=TRUE)
myReturn <- lag(position) * dailyReturn(symbol)

charts.PerformanceSummary(cbind(dailyReturn(symbol),myReturn))

Performance <- function(x) {

  cumRetx = Return.cumulative(x)
  annRetx = Return.annualized(x, scale=252)
  sharpex = SharpeRatio.annualized(x, scale=252) 
  winpctx = length(x[x > 0])/length(x[x != 0])
  annSDx = sd.annualized(x, scale=252)
  DDs <- findDrawdowns(x)
  maxDDx = min(DDs$return)
  maxLx = max(DDs$length)

  Perf = c(cumRetx, annRetx, sharpex, winpctx, annSDx, maxDDx, maxLx)
  names(Perf) = c("Cumulative Return", "Annual Return","Annualized Sharpe Ratio",
                  "Win %","Annualized Volatility", "Maximum Drawdown", "Max Length Drawdown")
  return(Perf)
}
cbind(STRAT=Performance(myReturn),BMK=Performance(dailyReturn(symbol)))
```

when executed this script is showing this error

```
Error in `[.xts`(x, x > 0) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

I am able to zero in the problem line and its is while calculating `winpctx = length(x[x > 0])/length(x[x != 0])` this problem occurs.

How to solve this error.

P.S. **Performance()** is taken from a website

Comment: When posting reproducible examples, it's bad form to include lines that remove all objects

Comment: @erasmortg sorry can you explain a bit more..not able to understand what you meant?

Comment: it will remove all of the objects in the environment, if someone copies your code like so. Also, it is not literally needed for a minimum example either

Comment: From where comes package `SIT`?

Comment: @erasmortg  sorry will not repeat that

Comment: @pascal ..SIT can be installed using   install.packages(SIT)

Comment: I get *Warning: package ‘SIT’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2 Patched)* And there is no `SIT` package in the list of packages available on CRAN.

Comment: @Pascal made a mistake.. i dont remeber how i installed sit only i have this recollection that i used curl some where

Comment: I guess you followed instructions here: https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT

Comment: yes. i followed that site. a long time back i installed sit so cant remember the exact procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
myReturn <- lag(position) * dailyReturn(symbol)
```

`position` is just a vector (not an xts object) so `lag.default` is dispatched and `lag.default` simply changes the `tsp` attribute (adding one if it doesn't exist). That makes `myReturn` a malformed xts object.

```
> str(lag(position))
 atomic [1:422] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 0 421 1
> str(myReturn)
Error in `[.xts`(x, 1, ) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

Fix that, and everything else works.

```
signals <- merge(buy.signal, sell.signal)
position <- xts(rowSums(signals, na.rm=TRUE), index(signals))
myReturn <- lag(position) * dailyReturn(symbol)
# set 1st obs to 0 (findDrawdowns complains if there are NA in the series)
myReturn[1] <- 0
```

Comment: does that means  **myReturn** i calculated using **position** is a garbage value. can changing **position** variable to **symbol$position** will change the problem?

Comment: @Eka: yes, it will work if you make `position` a column in the `symbol` object, because `symbol` is an xts object.